# Centering a paragraph in an inline-block column

Tags: html, css, text, centering, masonry

I got a masonry style grid like this:

```
  <div class="masonry">
      <div class="brick">
         <p>Img Title</p>
         <img src="img.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="brick"> 
       ....
      </div>
  </div>
```

With this css:

```
.masonry {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  column-gap: 00px;
  column-fill: initial;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.masonry .brick {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.masonry .brick p{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.masonry .brick img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**How would I center the p tag (vertical and horizontal) in the Masonry layout with css?**

Once I change the positioning to something like left=50% it goes to half of the wohle Masonry grid, not the one Masonry brick for some reason. An text-align: center doesn't seem to work at all.

The idea of course being: If you hover over one image it shows the title of the image in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below updated CSS

```
.masonry {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  column-gap: 00px;
  column-fill: initial;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.masonry .brick {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:relative;
}

.masonry .brick p{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    left:50%;
    margin:0;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}

.masonry .brick img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can use position:absolute with left:50% and top:50% to centre the element and you can translate it back half its width and height by using transform:translate(-50%, -50%). To consider the .brick element as the parent for the absolute p element, You have to add position:relative to it.

Comment: I didn't know you had to have position:relative on the parent element. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
.masonry .brick {
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   position:relative;
 }
 .masonry .brick p{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%;-50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:10;
 }
```

Absolute elements are positioned to first relative parent so you need to set your brick to be relative.... and then left:50% will work but it will be 50% from left and that isnt centered... so then you need to put it back by transforming it.. try and see :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` for horizontal and vertical center

```css
.masonry {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  column-gap: 00px;
  column-fill: initial;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
}

.masonry .brick {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.masonry .brick p{
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:red;
}

.masonry .brick img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="brick">
       <p>Img Title</p>
       <img src="http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png">
    </div>
    <div class="brick"> 
     ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the position `absolute` from the `p` tag.

```
.masonry .brick p{
  color: black;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```